# Swashbuckle configuration error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

I'm trying to add Swashbuckle into my ASP.NET MVC WebAPI project. I've started with an empty MVC project template in Visual Studio 2013. Later I added the required files/packages etc. But somehow I can't manage to integrate Swashbuckle into it. Everytime I run this code, gives the following error in `SwashConfig.cs`.

[image: Swashbuckle Config]

Following is my `web.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
  </system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer></configuration>
```

`package.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

`Global.asax.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace CDE.API
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => SwaggerConfig.Register(config));
        }
    }
}
```

`WebApiConfig.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace CDE.API
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
        }
    }
}
```

`SwaggerConfig.cs`

```
using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using CDE.API;
using Swashbuckle.Application;

//[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace CDE.API
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            config
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "CDE.API");
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\CDE.API.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
                    c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
                })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                });
        }
    }
}
```

`RouteConfig.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace CDE.API
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Something is very much wrong. Please help.

I'm using:

[image: System.Web.Http Version]

[image: System.Web.Http.WebHost Version]

Answer (score 1):

I think where your going wrong could be that you have commented out this line of code on the SwaggerConfig :-

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]
```

You have then decided to run this line of code after the RoutesConfig has registered all of the routes,

`GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => SwaggerConfig.Register(config))`;

You should try removing the line above, and try allowing SwaggerConfig to run on PreApplicationStartup as per default behaviour.

The error message, to me.. (Ive only used swagger with Web API) suggests that your trying to add the routes for swagger to0 late in the pipeline.

Good Luck.